# webpack 2 expose webworker as global

Tags: javascript, webpack, global, web-worker, webpack-2

I'm trying to write tests for a react/redux app, and we have a bunch of webworkers which are currently imported via `require('worker-loader?inline!downloadTrackWorker')`

I've been going in circles trying to figure out how to separate out this code so I can run tests in node.js without having trouble with loading the webworker.

One solution I came up with was to expose the webworker globally in my webpack, which would mean I could define a stub or mock in my tests.

In my webpack config, I've added

```
module: {
    loaders: [...],
    rules: [{
        test: require.resolve(APP_DIR + '/helpers/downloadTrackWorkerLoader'),
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'DownloadTrackWorker'
    }]
}
```

my trackWorkerLoader is simply

```
const DownloadTrackWorker = require('worker-loader?inline!./downloadTrackWorker.js');

module.export = DownloadTrackWorker;
```

I've also tried the above without `inline`, but no luck.

I'm experiencing two problems.

1. when I look for `DownloadTrackWorker` in my console, it is undefined
2. with my updated webpack.config, I get an error that webpack can't parse `may need appropriate loader` at

   ```
   ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Player />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
   );
   ```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? It appears to me the issues I'm seeing are related.

Comment: Webpack never exposes global. So you'll always get `DownloadTrackWorker` to be undefined you have to add 
`import DownloadTrackWorker from "path-to/trackWorkerLoader"` in whichever file you use it in.

Comment: @ApoorvJoshi am I misunderstanding this? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader I am using the expose loader. That says it adds to the global scope. Therefore I should not need to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I look for DownloadTrackWorker in my console, it is undefined

As the `expose-loader` notes in [Readme - Usage](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader#usage), you need to import it in order to be included in the bundle and therefore exposed. The rules are not including anything but are applied to the imports in your app which satisfy the test. Besides that you're also not applying the loader to the correct file. You want to apply the `expose-loader` to `trackWorkerLoader.js`, so the correct rule would be:

```
{
    test: require.resolve(APP_DIR + '/helpers/trackWorkerLoader'),
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: 'DownloadTrackWorker'
}
```

Now you need to import it somewhere in your app with:

```
require('./path/to/helpers/trackWorkerLoader');
```

This will correctly expose `DownloadTrackWorker` as a global variable, but you have a typo in `trackWorkerLoader.js` instead of `module.exports` you have `module.export`. Currently you're not actually exporting anything. It should be:

```
module.exports = DownloadTrackWorker;
```

Instead of inlining the `worker-loader` in the `require` (not talking about its option) you can also define it as a rule:

```
{
    test: require.resolve(APP_DIR + '/helpers/downloadTrackWorker'),
    loader: 'worker-loader',
    options: {
        inline: true
    }
}
```

And now you can simply require it without needing to specify the loaders in `trackWorkerLoader.js`:

```
const DownloadTrackWorker = require('./downloadTrackWorker');

module.exports = DownloadTrackWorker;
```

> with my updated webpack.config, I get an error that webpack can't parse may need appropriate loader

You're defining both `module.loaders` and `module.rules` at the same time. Although `module.loaders` still exists for compatibility reasons, it will be ignored completely if `module.rules` is present. Hence the loaders you configured before, are not being applied. Simply move all rules to `module.rules`.

Comment: You're right about the 'rules' Michael, thank you. As per needing to import, maybe I'm reading the docs wrong, but it specifically says `Alternately, you can set this in your config file:`. I took that to mean as an alternative to importing, which would suit my purpose well... Am I really reading that wrong? Strangely, even when importing in my index and calling from a child file, the `DownloadTrackWorker` is still undefined.

Comment: No, specifying in the config file is the alternative to inlining it, for example `require('expose-loader?options!./file.js')`. I elaborated the answer on the `expose-loader` and added the alternative to inlining the `worker-loader` (which is exactly what was meant for the `expose-loader`). It might have been a typo with `trackWorkerLoader` and `downloadTrackWorkerLoader` but I mentioned it anyway to be clear what you need to import.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this Michael, sadly, it means I'm barking up the wrong tree as I'm trying to create a global so that I don't have to reference the worker in my bundle. This will make it easier to test. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I ended up giving two entries in my webpack, I expose with `require('expose-loader?DownloadTrackWorker!worker-loader?inline!...)` this makes the webworker exposed globally in a worker.js bundle. No I can run my tests without including the worker in my packages.